# Vertical align a picture and a text

Tags: html, css

Im trying to get my picture (21x21px) and my text (14px) on the right side to vertivcally centered, but as soon as I put my picture in it, the `<a>` gets bigger.. how can I do it correctly?

the class "aPctr" is just giving the photo 21x21px

Heres my code: https://jsfiddle.net/vc0h9Ldb/

```
    <div id="cssmenu">
    <ul class="_mrgA">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active has-sub">
            <span class="submenu-button"></span>
            <a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="has-sub">
                    <span class="submenu-button"></span>
                    <a href="#">Product 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Product</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Product</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-sub">
                    <span class="submenu-button"></span>
                    <a href="#">Product 2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Product</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Product</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="account-lnk" style="float: right; height: 0;">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/autor.jpg" class="_aPctr">
                <span> Name</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Please use this,It is really help to you...***

```
<li class="account-lnk" style="float: right; height: 0px; position: relative; display: table;">
<a href="#" style="padding: 14px 20px;">
<img class="_aPctr" src="img/autor.jpg" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
<span style="vertical-align: middle;"> Name</span>
</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change padding for a in last li, it will work

```
#cssmenu > ul > li > a
{
padding: 15px 20px;
}
```

Code snippet also posted below

```css
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: "Lato",sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  top: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: auto;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  z-index:100;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  background-color: #00D4EB;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-color: #009ae1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: height .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: height .2s ease;
  -o-transition: height .2s ease;
  transition: height .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 32px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="cssmenu">
        <ul class="_mrgA">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active has-sub">
                <span class="submenu-button"></span>
                <a href="#">Products</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="has-sub">
                        <span class="submenu-button"></span>
                        <a href="#">Product 1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Sub Product</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Sub Product</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="has-sub">
                        <span class="submenu-button"></span>
                        <a href="#">Product 2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Sub Product</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Sub Product</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="account-lnk" style="float: right; height: 0;">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/autor.jpg" class="_aPctr">
                    <span> Name</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the padding of the last  tag which is using the same as others and it's contents are exceeding the height.

```
<li class="account-lnk" style="float: right; height: 0;">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/autor.jpg" class="_aPctr">
        <span> Name</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

For example, you can change it to this:

```
<li class="account-lnk" style="float: right; height: 0;">
    <a href="#" style="padding:16px;">
        <img src="img/autor.jpg" class="_aPctr">
        <span> Name</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

CHanging the CSS is up to you

Comment: yes, but then the left side is higher than the buttons

Comment: @Smythu. It could be not. You can simply control by customizing the css. Just customize the last one. play with the padding and get the final result. Try it ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can apply `vertical-align: middle;` on the img. Then it looks like this:

```css
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: "Lato",sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  top: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: auto;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  z-index:100;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  background-color: #00D4EB;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-color: #009ae1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: height .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: height .2s ease;
  -o-transition: height .2s ease;
  transition: height .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 32px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
#img-vertical{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
 <div id="cssmenu">
  <ul class="_mrgA">
   <li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="active has-sub">
    <span class="submenu-button"></span>
    <a href="#">Products</a>
    <ul>
     <li class="has-sub">
      <span class="submenu-button"></span>
      <a href="#">Product 1</a>
      <ul>
       <li>
        <a href="#">Sub Product</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">Sub Product</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="has-sub">
      <span class="submenu-button"></span>
      <a href="#">Product 2</a>
      <ul>
       <li>
        <a href="#">Sub Product</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">Sub Product</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">About</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
   </li>
   <li class="account-lnk" style="float: right; height: 0;">
    <a href="#">
     <img id="img-vertical" src="img/autor.jpg" class="_aPctr">
     <span> Name</span>
    </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

I took the CSS from your fiddle for this demo.